# Declaring functions two ways. What is the distinction?

Tags: scala

Are these two function declarations effectively different?

If not, why do they have different toString values?

```
scala> def f: (Int) => Int = x=> x*x
f: (Int) => Int

scala> def f(x: Int) = x*x
f: (Int)Int
```

Comment: it is not an answer, but I guess the second has the return type inferred and that is the difference, because afaik Scala has operator overloading which means x*x does not have to be an Int.

Comment: @Gabriel: No, there's no truth in that.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The first is a no-argument method `f1` that returns a `Function1[Int, Int]`.

```
scala> def f1: (Int => Int) = (x: Int) => x * x
f1: (Int) => Int
```

The second is a one argument method `f2` that takes an an `Int` and returns an `Int`.

```
scala> def f2(x: Int): Int = x * x
f2: (x: Int)Int
```

You can invoke f1 and f2 with the same syntax, although when you call `f1(2)` it is expanded to `f1.apply(2)`.

```
scala> f1
res0: (Int) => Int = <function1>

scala> f1(2)
res1: Int = 4

scala> f1.apply(2)
res2: Int = 2

scala> f2(2)
res3: Int = 4
```

Finally, you can 'lift' the method `f2` to a function as follows.

```
scala> f2
<console>:6: error: missing arguments for method f2 in object $iw;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied funct
ion
       f2
       ^

scala> f2 _
res7: (Int) => Int = <function1>

scala> (f2 _).apply(2)
res8: Int = 4
```

**Exercise**: What is the type of `f1 _`?

Comment: A no-arg function, returning a function that maps Int to Int.

scala> f1 _
res6: () => (Int) => Int = <function>

Interestingly we can keep "lifting"...

scala> res6 _
res7: () => () => (Int) => Int = <function>

scala> res7 _
res8: () => () => () => (Int) => Int = <function>

scala> res8()()()(9)
res9: Int = 81

Thanks for the info @retronym. The exercise is a nice touch!

Comment: BTW, the precise term for this conversion in Scala is Eta Expansion. See '6.7 Method Values' and '6.25.5 Eta Expansion' in http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf

Answer (score 4):

These are methods declarations, not function declarations. The first method returns a function, the second returns an `Int` and has nothing to do with functions.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529184/difference-between-method-and-function-in-scala).