# Scala - get function name

Tags: scala

I have a function `foo` which takes another function (say `bar`) as a parameter. Is there a way to get the function name of `bar` as a string inside `foo`?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the name" of the function?

Comment: Say I pass a function called bar into foo. Inside foo, I receive this function with a parameter call baz. I want to print "bar", i.e. the name of the function passed in.

Comment: Am I getting it right? You actually want the reference `bar`, which referred to the function before it was passed into the scope of `foo` as a parameter and became `baz`. If so, then there is no way in hell you could do that.

Comment: I am not able rightly to apprehend the kind of confusion of ideas that could provoke such a question.

Comment: @agilesteel - I am basically looking to do something like a toString on the parameter passed in to get "bar". Don't think it's possible looking at the other answers..

Comment: If you describe the reason why you want to do this, you might get some useful alternative solutions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No. See the [difference between methods and functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009411/two-ways-of-defining-functions-in-scala-what-is-the-difference). Methods aren't passed as parameters under the hood - they are expanded into function objects when being passed to some other method/function. These function objects are instances of anonymous, compiler-generated classes , and have no name (or, at least, being anonymous classes, have some mangled name which you could access using reflection, but probably don't need).

So, when you do:

```
def foo() {}

def bar(f: () => Unit) {}

bar(foo)
```

what actually happens in the last call is:

```
bar(() => foo())
```

Theoretically, though, you could find the name of the method that the function object you're being passed is wrapping. You could do bytecode introspection to analyze the body of the `apply` method of the function object `f` in method `bar` above, and conclude based on that what the name of the method is. This is both an approximation and an overkill, however.

Answer (score 2):

I've had quite a dig around, and I don't think that there is. `toString` on the function object just says eg `<function1>`, and its class is a synthesised class generated by the compiler rather that something with a `method` object inside it that you might query.

I guess that if you really needed this there would be nothing to stop you implementing `function` with something that delegated but also knew the name of the thing to which it was delegating.