# Declare a function using def or var in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm trying to figure out the difference between `def` and `var/val` when declaring a function in Scala.

Say we have a function:

```
scala> def f(x: Int) = { x * 2 }
f: (x: Int)Int
```

And another function g:

```
scala> var g = (x:Int) => x*2
g: Int => Int = <function1>
```

Apparently they are the same in the following way:

```
scala> f(2)
res0: Int = 4

scala> g(2)
res1: Int = 4
```

However, I could do

```
g = f
g: Int => Int = <function1>
```

but not

```
scala> f = g
<console>:13: error: missing arguments for method f;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
val $ires6 = f
             ^
<console>:10: error: reassignment to val
       f = g
         ^
```

**Question 1**: why does this happen? *I'm guessing that `def` maps to `val`*.

**Question 2**: if I use *val* instead of *var* in declare *g*, are they equivalent? If not, what is the difference then?

I then try:

```
scala> def three( timetwo:(Int) => Int ) = { timetwo(3) } 
three: (timetwo: Int => Int)Int

scala> three(g)
res47: Int = 6

scala> three(f)
res48: Int = 6
```

**Question 3**: does it mean `(x: Int)Int` is the same as `Int => Int = <function1>`? If so, is there some situation that we should favor one over the other?

Things is getting wired with the `_` (underscore),

```
scala> three(f _)
res49: Int = 6

scala> three(g _)
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;
found   : () => Int => Int
required: Int => Int
          three(g _)
                ^
```

**Question 4**: why does this happen? What's the usage of `_`(underline) in Scala?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Two ways of defining functions in Scala. What is the difference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009411/two-ways-of-defining-functions-in-scala-what-is-the-difference)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529184/difference-between-method-and-function-in-scala

Answer (score 6):

> why does this happen? I'm guessing that def maps to val.

`def` is a method (in JVM terms) so it doesn't make sense to assign it.

The parser is then confused and it ultimately tries to save the day by interpreting the assignment `f = g` as

```
val $ires6 = f
f = g
```

Both statements are illegal, so you get two errors:

- you can't assign a method to a `val` without an explicit type annotation or a `_` expansion - see below)
- you can't reassign a `val` (in case you are wondering, `$ires6` is a fresh `val` introduced by the REPL)

> if I use val instead of var in declare g, are they equivalent? If not, what is the difference then?

The difference is that `val` cannot be reassigned (i.e. it's a constant reference), whereas `var` can (i.e. it's a mutable reference).

More on the subject here: [What is the difference between a var and val definition in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791408/what-is-the-difference-between-a-var-and-val-definition-in-scala)

> does it mean (x: Int)Int is the same as Int => Int = ? If so, is there some situation that we should favor one over the other?

[Methods and functions are not the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529184/difference-between-method-and-function-in-scala), although the compiler does its best to make you believe they are, through a transformation called eta-expansion. In some cases such transformation can be performed automatically, in some others you need to be explicit and trigger it with a trailing `_`.

In your specific example (passing a method where a function is expected) the expansion can been performed automatically.

You can read [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009411/two-ways-of-defining-functions-in-scala-what-is-the-difference) for a more in-depth discussion about which style to prefer.

> why does this happen? What's the usage of _(underline) in Scala?

The underscore (`_`) [has many uses in scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000903/what-are-all-the-uses-of-an-underscore-in-scala), one of which is the one I mentioned before, i.e. triggering the eta expansion of a method into a function.

That's a special syntax for methods, so you simply can't apply it to a function, as it would make no sense.

That's why you can do `f _` (which will turn the `f` method into a function), but you can't do `g _` (since `g` it's already a function).