# Reading a scala function

Tags: scala, function

I was reading [this page](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-sql-udfs.html), and I came across this function definition in scala:

```
def upper: String => String = _.toUpperCase
```

After trying it out, it seems that it works the same as this:

```
def upper = (str: String) => str.toUpperCase()
```

Are both functions the same? If so, how do I read the above function (first one)? does this way of defining definitions have a specific name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is actually not a function but a method.
You can read about the difference between the two [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529184/difference-between-method-and-function-in-scala) [and here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839537/functions-vs-methods-in-scala)

Both of this are the same it's a method called upper with no parameters that returns a function from String to String.

```
def upper: String => String = _.toUpperCase
```

`String => String` is the return type of upper. what comes after the equal sign is the implementation. The underscore is just a syntactic sugar used to refer the function parameter.

Comment: Actually, it is a method that returns a function. Plus, `String => String` is not the signature but the return type of `upper`, to be precise. Maybe the OP wanted something like `def upper(str: String) = str.toUpperCase`, which is the normal way of defining a method that accepts a string and returns a string?

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet It is indeed the return type. updated. Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

> I was reading […], and I came across this function definition in scala:
>
> ```
> def upper: String => String = _.toUpperCase
> ```

That is *not* a function definition. That's a *method* definition, which is something very different.

> After trying it out, it seems that it works the same as this:
>
> ```
> def upper = (str: String) => str.toUpperCase()
> ```

Yes, that's exactly the same thing.

> Are both functions the same?

Both *methods* are the same. (They aren't functions, they are methods.)

> If so, how do I read the above function (first one)? does this way of defining definitions have a specific name?

It's not quite clear what you mean by "this way". Both are just normal method definitions. There are four differences between the two:

- In the first definition, the return type of the method is explicitly annotated, in the second definition, it is left to the compiler to be inferred. The name for the first feature is "type annotation" or "explicit typing", the name for the second feature is "type inference" or "implicit typing".
- The first definition uses *placeholder syntax* to construct the function to be returned from the method, the second definition uses a *function literal*.
- In the second definition, the parameter for the anonymous function is *explicitly annotated with a type*, in the first definition, it isn't even mentioned, since we use placeholder syntax.
- In the first definition, `toUpperCase` is called without an argument list, in the second definition, `toUpperCase` is called with an empty argument list. `toUpperCase` is actually defined with an empty parameter list, so it *should* be called with an empty argument list; however, Scala allows calling a method that is defined with an empty parameter list without an argument list (but not the other way around, because of the obvious ambiguity). (Note that according to the community Scala style guide, `toUpperCase` should be defined without a parameter list because it has no side-effects; however, in the original implementation of Scala, it is actually implemented as a Java method and Java methods must always have exactly one parameter list, it is impossible to define a Java method without a parameter list.)

Note that this should rather be a `val` than a `def`, though: a `val` is only evaluated once, when it is initialized, a `def` is evaluated every time it is called. But this `def` always returns the same thing anyway, so you could just as well make it a `val`. (Or a `lazy val` if you want to avoid constructing a function that may not be needed.)

I also noticed that you tagged your question with [callbyname](/questions/tagged/callbyname), but there is no call-by-name here. Everything is call-by-value in this example.

Here are a couple of other ways to write that same method:

```
def upper: Function1[String, String] = (str: String) => str.toUpperCase()
```

This is the most explicit one, all the others are just leaving stuff out from this one and leaving it to the compiler to figure out. But in all cases, the compiler will figure out *this* and the compiled code will be identical.

Option 1: use infix type constructor syntax for the generic return type of the method:

```
def upper: String Function1 String = (str: String) => str.toUpperCase()
//         ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
```

Option 2: use the syntactic sugar for function types for the generic return type of the method:

```
def upper: String => String = (str: String) => str.toUpperCase()
//         ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
```

Option 3: leave out the explicit type of the function parameter:

```
def upper: Function1[String, String] = str => str.toUpperCase()
//                                     ↑↑↑
```

Option 4: leave out the explicit return type of the method:

```
def upper = (str: String) => str.toUpperCase()
//      ↑↑↑
```

Option 5: leave out the empty argument list of `toUpperCase`:

```
def upper: Function1[String, String] = (str: String) => str.toUpperCase
//                                                                    ↑↑
```

Option 6: use placeholder syntax for the function:

```
def upper: Function1[String, String] = _.toUpperCase()
//                                     ↑
```

You can also combine several of these options, e.g. #3, #5, and #6:

```
def upper: String => String = _.toUpperCase
```

However! You need at least one type annotation, so that the compiler can either figure out the parameter type of the function from the return type of the method or figure out the return type of the method from the type of the function. Leaving out *both* won't work:

```
def upper = str => str.toUpperCase()
// <console>:11: error: missing parameter type
//            def upper = str => str.toUpperCase()
//                        ^

def upper = _.toUpperCase()
// <console>:11: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1: <error>) => x$1.toUpperCase())
//            def upper = _.toUpperCase()
//                        ^
```

(By the way, here you can also see how the compiler expands the placeholder syntax.)

Last but not least, you can use `⇒` instead of `=>` both for the function type:

```
def upper: String ⇒ String = (str: String) => str.toUpperCase()
```

And the function literal:

```
def upper: Function1[String, String] = (str: String) ⇒ str.toUpperCase()
```

If I haven't miscounted, then this gives you a total of 44 different ways of expressing this same method:

```
def upper = (str: String) ⇒ str.toUpperCase
def upper = (str: String) ⇒ str.toUpperCase()
def upper = (str: String) => str.toUpperCase
def upper = (str: String) => str.toUpperCase()
def upper: Function1[String, String] = _.toUpperCase
def upper: Function1[String, String] = _.toUpperCase()
def upper: Function1[String, String] = (str: String) ⇒ str.toUpperCase
def upper: Function1[String, String] = (str: String) ⇒ str.toUpperCase()
def upper: Function1[String, String] = (str: String) => str.toUpperCase
def upper: Function1[String, String] = (str: String) => str.toUpperCase()
def upper: Function1[String, String] = str ⇒ str.toUpperCase
def upper: Function1[String, String] = str ⇒ str.toUpperCase()
def upper: Function1[String, String] = str => str.toUpperCase
def upper: Function1[String, String] = str => str.toUpperCase()
def upper: String ⇒ String = _.toUpperCase
def upper: String ⇒ String = _.toUpperCase()
def upper: String ⇒ String = (str: String) ⇒ str.toUpperCase
def upper: String ⇒ String = (str: String) ⇒ str.toUpperCase()
def upper: String ⇒ String = (str: String) => str.toUpperCase
def upper: String ⇒ String = (str: String) => str.toUpperCase()
def upper: String ⇒ String = str ⇒ str.toUpperCase
def upper: String ⇒ String = str ⇒ str.toUpperCase()
def upper: String ⇒ String = str => str.toUpperCase
def upper: String ⇒ String = str => str.toUpperCase()
def upper: String => String = _.toUpperCase
def upper: String => String = _.toUpperCase()
def upper: String => String = (str: String) ⇒ str.toUpperCase
def upper: String => String = (str: String) ⇒ str.toUpperCase()
def upper: String => String = (str: String) => str.toUpperCase
def upper: String => String = (str: String) => str.toUpperCase()
def upper: String => String = str ⇒ str.toUpperCase
def upper: String => String = str ⇒ str.toUpperCase()
def upper: String => String = str => str.toUpperCase
def upper: String => String = str => str.toUpperCase()
def upper: String Function1 String = _.toUpperCase
def upper: String Function1 String = _.toUpperCase()
def upper: String Function1 String = (str: String) ⇒ str.toUpperCase
def upper: String Function1 String = (str: String) ⇒ str.toUpperCase()
def upper: String Function1 String = (str: String) => str.toUpperCase
def upper: String Function1 String = (str: String) => str.toUpperCase()
def upper: String Function1 String = str ⇒ str.toUpperCase
def upper: String Function1 String = str ⇒ str.toUpperCase()
def upper: String Function1 String = str => str.toUpperCase
def upper: String Function1 String = str => str.toUpperCase()
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps a LOT! very useful and consolidated information for people new to Scala.

Comment: I just realized I missed two more options, bringing the total count of possible variations to 44.

Answer (score 3):

> Are both functions the same?

Yes, *both methods* are the same. The latter is expanded by the compiler to match the former. This syntax is known as [placeholder syntax for anonymous functions](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#placeholder-syntax-for-anonymous-functions).

This definition is a method which yields a function. In Scala, methods and functions behave differently, as methods don't have a value (also called [non-value types](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html#non-value-types)).

Comment: Great answer. !

Answer (score 0):

**Both are methods returning a function object, on which the passed argument will be applied.**

The first method returns a function object (shorthand for `Function[A, B]`), so with explicit defn that it `takes A(String) and emits B(String)`. (Static typing)

```
scala> def toUpperMethod: Function[String,String] = { case x => x.toUpperCase }
toUpperMethod: Function[String,String]

scala> toUpperMethod.apply("apply me") //.apply() is optional
res9: String = APPLY ME

scala> toUpperMethod("apply me")
res10: String = APPLY ME
```

While the second is anonymous method that returns a function object too which takes `String` but can return `Any`,

```
scala> def toUpperAnonymous = (x: String) => x.contains("hello") match { case true => x.toUpperCase case false => x.length } 
upperFun: String => Any

scala> toUpperAnonymous.apply("hello") //.apply() is optional
res8: Any = HELLO

scala> toUpperAnonymous("yello")
res9: Any = 5
```

**A traditional method returning a value(not a function object as in above examples) would be as below, which does not have a `apply` function.**

```
scala> def toUpperPureMethod(x: String) : String = x.toUpperCase
toUpperPureMethod: (x: String)String //has type (input)output

scala> toUpperPureMethod.apply("scala")
<console>:14: error: missing argument list for method toUpperPureMethod
Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected.
You can make this conversion explicit by writing `toUpperPureMethod _` or `toUpperPureMethod(_)` instead of `toUpperPureMethod`.
       toUpperPureMethod.apply("scala")
```

But it can be wrapped to return as a function as below,

```
scala> def methodReturningFunction = toUpperPureMethod _
methodReturningFunction: String => String

scala> methodReturningFunction.apply("process me")
res11: String = PROCESS ME
```

### [NOTE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5011434/432903)

- anything of type `input => output` is a function type.
- anything of type `input(output)` denotes a method