# Why does a partial function applied to 2 functions that do the same thing defined in 2 different ways return a different result?

Tags: scala

I can define the following two functions:

```
def add(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int) = a + b + c
```

this results in

```
add: (a: Int, b: Int, c: Int)Int
```

and

```
val add2 = (a: Int, b: Int, c: Int) => a + b + c
```

this results in

```
add2: (Int, Int, Int) => Int = <function3>
```

Both of these are functions that do the exact same thing but defined in a different way, what I do not understand is if I go ahead and define a partially applied function as follows:

```
def a = add _
```

This results in

```
a: (Int, Int, Int) => Int = <function3>
```

as expected, a function that takes 3 parameters and returns an Int, but if I do

```
def a2 = add2 _
```

This results in

```
a2: () => (Int, Int, Int) => Int = <function0>
```

which seems to be a function that takes no parameters and returns a function that takes 3 Int parameters and returns an Int. Why does this happen? Can someone please explain what is going on?

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Declaring functions two ways. What is the distinction?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720486/declaring-functions-two-ways-what-is-the-distinction)

Comment: That duplicate was the third related link. Really, do try to look for previously asked question -- this one has been asked many, many times. While I think that link is a closest duplicate, I personally recommend [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529184/difference-between-method-and-function-in-scala/2530007#2530007) of mine to get to the bottom of the subject.

Comment: Oh, by the way, perhaps you'll be clearer if you write `def add2` instead of `val add2`.

Comment: Just noticed from a deleted answer you originally wrote `def` instead of `val`. Well, the difference between `def` and `val` is that the former computes the value every time it is called, while the latter computes it once and returns the pre-computed value when called.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a strange side-effect of Scala not actually having (user-accessible) fields, but instead having accessors (getters) for everything.  Observe:

```
scala> val i = 1
i: Int = 1

scala> i _
res0: () => Int = <function0>
```

The reason is that `i` is actually an accessor (`def i: Int`) to an underlying (hidden, inaccessible) field.  Since it's just a method, `_` will convert it into a function.  The accessor doesn't take any arguments, which is why you have a function that takes no parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Scala has both functions and methods, they are not quite the same thing.

```
def add(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int) = a + b + c
```

Which defined a method (not a function!!).

```
val add2 = (a: Int, b: Int, c: Int) => a + b + c
```

Which assigned add2 a function value(not a method!!).

A method can’t be the final value, while a function can:

```
scala> add
<console>:9: error: missing arguments for method add;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
              add
              ^

scala> add2
res1: (Int, Int, Int) => Int = <function3>

scala> val a = add
<console>:8: error: missing arguments for method add;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
       val a = add
               ^

scala> val a2 = add2
a2: (Int, Int, Int) => Int = <function3>
```

Writing an underscore after the method name can explicitly convert a method into a function:

```
scala> add _
res2: (Int, Int, Int) => Int = <function3>
```

But if you writing an underscore after a value, it will convert to a function which take no argument with return type of its type:

```
scala> val s = ""
s: String = ""

scala> val i = 1
i: Int = 1

scala> s _
res3: () => String = <function0>

scala> i _
res4: () => Int = <function0>
```

So if the value itself is a function, writing an underscore after it will get a new function which take no argument with return type of function:

```
scala> add2 _
res5: () => (Int, Int, Int) => Int = <function0>
```

Answer (score 1):

Effect is clearly described in [Rex Kerr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9543679/210905) but you should note that `add2` is value already representing partially applied function, e.g. delegate.
For demonstrating you could compare types of `add1 _` expression and `add2`  value.

```
scala> def getManifest[T](x:T)(implicit m:scala.reflect.Manifest[T]) = m
getManifest: [T](x: T)(implicit m: scala.reflect.Manifest[T])scala.reflect.Manifest[T]

scala> getManifest(add1 _) == getManifest(add2)
res14: Boolean = true
```